# How do I add multiple custom vertical lines to individual facets in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations

I've seen the question posted before but the seemingly simple solution is not working for me. I'm trying to add horizontal lines indicating treatment date on my faceted ggplot but keep getting an error.

ggplot code:

```
p <- ggplot(mastersumm, aes(x = date, y = count, group = type)) +
  geom_point(size = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = type)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = count-se, ymax = count+se), width=.2) +
  facet_grid(mastersumm$treatment, scales = "fixed", labeller = labeller(type = long_types, treatment = long_types)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill='white', colour='black'), legend.position = "top") +
  scale_fill_grey()
```

which produces:

[image]

I've tried making a custom data frame for the custom lines to be added. I included an NA value for the control as it should not receive a vertical line. I included the factor `both` twice as it is to receive two vertical lines:

```
treatment <- as.factor(c("control", "early", "late", "both", "both"))
date <- c("", "2013-05-23", "2013-06-04", "2013-05-23", "2013-06-04")
date <- as.Date(date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
vline.df <- data.frame(treatment, date)
```

which produces:

```
> vline.df
  treatment       date
1   control       <NA>
2     early 2013-05-23
3      late 2013-06-04
4      both 2013-05-23
5      both 2013-06-04
```

The `treatment` and `date` are of the same class as those in the receiving ggplot (factor, date, respectively).

Finally, I try the following input:

```
p + geom_vline(data = vline.df, aes(xintercept = date))
```

only to receive the following error:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "PANEL", value = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,  :
> replacement has 40 rows, data has 5

Comment: I found my problem was using mastersumm$treatment in the facet_grid call. Changing it to treatment messed up my graph but at least allowed me to add the lines. So now I just need to fix the graph.

Comment: Your approach works fine on my machine with my data.